# Trouble accessing backref parameters in HTML using SQLAlchemy and Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an HTML page (simplified below) where I am trying to access some table data using a backref.  The HTML `{% for buyer in company.buyer%} {% if buyer is none %}` references the backref `buyer` of the *Company* table to give me access to the *Buyers* table.

From there, I would like to get use the backref from the *Buyer* table (edetails) to get the information from the *Eventdetails* table.

Where this doesn't work is when I try to access the information of the *Eventdetails* table. `{{ buyer.edetails.naics}}` No information populates.  Is it possible to use two different backrefs together?  Thank you!

**company.html** | simplified for easier reading

```
          <div class="container">
            {% for buyer in company.buyer%} {% if buyer is none %}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm">
                No company has been added.
              </div>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <!--This is where I start the internal table-->
            <div class="container border bg-light">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  {{buyer.firstname}} {{buyer.lastname}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <!--THIS CODE DOESN'T POPULATE ANY INFORMATION-->
                  <p> {{ buyer.edetails.naics}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %} {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class CompanyView(MethodView):

    decorators = [login_required]
    template_file = 'company.html'

    def get(self, comp_id, event_id):
        company = Company.query.filter_by(id=comp_id).first()
        print(f'The company is {company.company}')
        events = Events.query.filter_by(id=event_id).first()
        print(f'The event is {events.eventname}')
        return render_template(self.template_file, company=company, events=events)
```

The models are shown listed here

**models.py**

```
Class Company(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    company_url = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    duns = db.Column(db.String(11))
    event_id = db.relationship(
        'Events', secondary=event_company, backref='event', lazy='dynamic'
    )
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    # Company is parent to the buyer
    buyer = db.relationship('Buyers', backref='buyer', lazy='dynamic')


class Buyers(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'buyers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    company = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
    edetails = db.relationship('Eventdetails', backref='edetails', lazy='dynamic')
    schedule = db.relationship('Buyerschedule', backref='schedule', lazy='dynamic')

class Eventdetails(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'eventdetails'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    schedule_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    events_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
    buyer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buyers.id'))
    naics = db.Column(db.Integer)
    buyer_schedule_id = db.relationship(
        'Buyerschedule', backref='buyer_sched_id', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in `buyer.edetails.naics`, you don't need to use the backrefs. It's just the Buyer relationship to Eventdetails.

The way it's set up right now, `buyer.edetails` will return a list. So you'd probably get an error if you try to access `buyer.edetails.naics`

If there is truly a one-to-one relationship between buyers and eventdetails then you can configure the relationship as such:

```
class Buyers(db.Model, UserMixin):
...
    edetails = db.relationship('Eventdetails', backref='edetails', lazy='dynamic', uselist=False)
```

You might also have to specify that the `eventdetails.buyer_id` column is unique.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you for helping me outside of my "loop".  I had forgotten that this would be a list.  Thank you!